# How to do Role Based Access Control in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm working on my school project for building a workshop tools inventory system using `CodeIgniter`.

Currently, I want to make 1 Page but for different user **role/level**.
So the example is like this, there is a page of tool list that admin and user can see. But the admin can edit the tool while the user can't edit or see the edit button from that page.

what I want to do is just that, so I can make 1 page instead of 2 pages for admin and user.
I have made the session for user and admin. just wanted to see if I can make few pages rather than make different pages for admin and user.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Yes you can use session for that, use that sessions on your controller. You can manipulate it (conditional to check the privilege of the user) on every start on the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming `admin` has `role_id = 1` and `user` has `role_id = 2`

you can create a button in your view : like this

```php
$role_id = $this->session->userdata('role_id');

if($role_id === 1){
    //it means this block will executed if has role_id = 1
    echo '<button> Add </button>'
}
```

Comment: oh hell why i don't think about that XD.. thank you!